# Configuring Pusher on Vue3

Tags: vue.js, websocket, real-time, vuejs3, pusher

I have a project in Vue3 and want to implement a real time API or a web socket. So I attempted to use pusher using Vue third part libraries which are **pusher-vue and vue-pusher**. Using **pusher-vue** I am getting the error: **Uncaught TypeError: e.prototype is undefined**. Using **vue-pusher** I am getting the error: **Uncaught TypeError: Vue.prototype is undefined**. The following are the libraries' configurations:

**PUSHER VUE**

**Component.vue**

```js
export default{
  channels: {
       applications_channel: {
           subscribeOnMount: true,
           subscribed(){
               console.log("Some text")
           },

           bind:{
               add_application_event(data){
                   console.log(data)
               }
           }
       }
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```js
createApp(App)
.use(PusherVue, {
    app_key: "MY_KEY",
    cluster: 'MY_CLUSTER',
    debug: true,
    debugLevel: "all"
})
.mount("#app")
```

**VUE PUSHER**

**Component.vue**

```js
export default{
  read(){
      var channel = this.$pusher.subscribe('applications-channel')

            channel.bind('add-application-event', ({ log }) => {
                console.log(log);
            })
       }
}
```

**main.js**

```js
createApp(App)
.use(require("vue-pusher"), {
    api_key: "MY_KEY",
    options: {
        cluster: 'MY_CLUSTER',
        ecrypted: true,
    }
})
.mount("#app")
```

May you please help with how can I configure this on Vue3 or recommend any beginner friendly alternatives to achieve the same functionality on Vue3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `pusher-vue` and `vue-pusher` were built for Vue 2, so you need to use the Vue 3 [migration build](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/migration-build.html#overview) to make the library work in your project.

To setup your Vue CLI scaffolded project:

1. Install the Vue compatibility build and SFC compiler that matches your Vue build version (i.e., install `@vue/compat@^3.1.0` and `@vue/compiler-sfc@^3.1.0` if you have `vue@^3.1.0` in `package.json`):

   ```bash
   npm i -S @vue/compat@^3.1.0
   npm i -S @vue/compiler-sfc@^3.1.0
   ```
2. Configure Webpack to alias `vue` to the `@vue/compat` build, and set `vue-loader`'s compatibility mode to Vue 2:

   ```js
   // vue.config.js
   module.exports = {
     chainWebpack: config => {
       config.resolve.alias.set('vue', '@vue/compat')

       config.module
         .rule('vue')
         .use('vue-loader')
         .tap(options => {
           return {
             ...options,
             compilerOptions: {
               compatConfig: {
                 MODE: 2
               }
             }
           }
         })
     }
   }
   ```

[demo: `vue-pusher` in Vue 3 w/migration build](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-dat-gui-demo?file=vue.config.js)

However, `vue-pusher` 1.1.0 seems to [only expose a new instance of Pusher](https://unpkg.com/vue-pusher@1.1.0/index.js) (from [`pusher-js`](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js)) as `this.$pusher` on the Vue instance. That code could easily be migrated to Vue 3 as a plugin:

```js
// plugins/pusher.js
export default (app, { apiKey, ...options }) => {
  const Pusher = require('pusher-js')
  app.config.globalProperties.$pusher = new Pusher(apiKey, options)
}

// main.js
const { createApp } = require('vue')
import App from './App.vue'
import PusherPlugin from './plugins/pusher'

createApp(App)
  .use(PusherPlugin, { apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY', cluster: 'YOUR_CLUSTER' })
  .mount('#app')
```

[demo: `pusher-js` in Vue 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-pusher?file=src%2Fmain.js)

Comment: Yes, both approaches would work: (1) Use migration build, or (2) manually set it up yourself in Vue 3 (without the migration build), assuming it's a very simple library.